# Unable to read file from directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following Directory structure,

```
F:\TestData
```

and TestData contains 20 folders with name `node1, node2,..., node20`
and each node folder contains file with names `log.10.X`

I need to access each log file from all node folders, For which I have writen code, but it is saying, `File not found - log.*`

CODE:

```
directory = "F:\TestData"
p = subprocess.Popen(["find", "./" + directory, "-name", "log.*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
foutput = output.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, unlike POSIX shells, does not automatically do globbing (interpreting `*` and the like as wildcards related to files in the relevant directory) in strings. It does, however, provide [a `glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for that purpose. You can use this to get a list of matching filenames:

```
import glob

filenames = glob.glob(r'F:\TestData\node*\log.*')
```

Comment: It is showing small problem, it is giving correct paths but with extra backslash. Like I am getting F:\\TestData\\node1\\log.10.17.0.0 instead of F:\CRLOG1\node1\log.10.17.0.0

Comment: If you are getting the `repr()`esentation of the strings (including using the interpreter without `print`), they will be surrounded in quotes and backslashes will be escaped (with another backslash).

Comment: i did print `myrepr.repr(filenames)` it is showing same result. Is this what you were saying or did I understood it wrong? Sorry

Comment: No—_don't_ print the representation. The representation of a string is what you would type into the interpreter to get the string, enclosing quotes, escape sequences and all. Just print the filename itself (e.g. `print filenames[0]`). Note that the representation and the string version of lists are the same, so `print filenames` and `print repr(filenames)` will also show the strings with enclosing quotes and escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use python to get a list of files in the directory

```
import os
directory = "F:\TestData\"
file_list = os.listdir(directory)
log_list = filter(lambda x: x.startswith("log"), file_list)
```

oh, you have to code to iterate sub directory. 
First `os.listdir()`in the parent directory ,and iterate the sub directory to get the files

Comment: Double backslashes or a single forward slash!

Answer (score 0):

Python's glob module may be an option.

```
import glob
directory = 'F:\TestData'
logcontents = [open(f,'r').read() for f in glob.glob(directory + '\node*\log.*')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use `walk`, like this:

```
import os
directory = "F:\TestData"
for i in os.walk(directory):
    # i like this:
    # ('F:\\TestData', ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'], [])
    # ('F:\\TestData\\node1', [], ['log.1.txt'])
    # ('F:\\TestData\\node2', [], ['log.2.txt'])
    print i
    if i[2] != []:
        # TODO: use the path to finish other
        # If dictory noden have some log file, you should use i[2][n].
        # So, if you only need log.n.txt, you only use i[2][n].
        print os.path.join(i[0], i[2][0])
```

Comment: I would use [iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) for the return value of `os.walk()`. Also, remember to filter out directories whose names do not begin with `'node'`.